# How to input number-series (with appointed amount) in Emacs?

Tags: rectangle

I want to input 90 number-series starts from 1, here is what I did:

```
set-mark
type enter 90 times
C-u C-x r N Enter %3d Enter
```

The output is like this:

```
1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
....
90
```

Is there a way to set the amount of output? (I don't want to hit enter / or hold enter for 90 times.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's [tiny](https://github.com/abo-abo/tiny)'s time to shine:

```
m\n90
```

will expand (with `tiny-expand`) to what you want.

There's also rich formatting and templating that can be applied.

- `m5|%02d`:

  ```
  00 01 02 03 04 05
  ```
- `m7|%(expt 2 x)`:

  ```
  1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128
  ```
- `m1\n5|*** TODO http://emacsrocks.com/e%02d.html`:

  ```
  *** TODO http://emacsrocks.com/e01.html
  *** TODO http://emacsrocks.com/e02.html
  *** TODO http://emacsrocks.com/e03.html
  *** TODO http://emacsrocks.com/e04.html
  *** TODO http://emacsrocks.com/e05.html
  ```
- `m\n3|* TODO Wash dog\nDEADLINE: <%(date "Oct 14" (* x 4))>`

  ```
  * TODO Wash dog
  DEADLINE: <2015-10-14 Wed>
  * TODO Wash dog
  DEADLINE: <2015-10-18 Sun>
  * TODO Wash dog
  DEADLINE: <2015-10-22 Thu>
  * TODO Wash dog
  DEADLINE: <2015-10-26 Mon>
  ```

`tiny` is available in MELPA.

Comment: Wow, this is really a powerful package. We should let more people know this package.

Comment: I'll do a post about it on http://oremacs.com/ soon.

Answer (score 11):

As another answer suggests, you can insert 90 new lines using prefix argument `90` like this: `C-u 90 RET`. Then insert the number list using `C-u C-x r N` as you did. However, if you want a more flexible format of numbered list, you can use [Keyboard Macro counter](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macro-Counter.html).

I included some exercises in [my guide](http://tuhdo.github.io/emacs-tutor.html#sec-7-31-2). Here is one:

> **Exercise 1**: Creating incremental header prefix
>
> Format specification is useful for making formatted output with macro,
>   combine with the counter, it is useful for appending numbered prefix
>   at beginning of line. For example: We usually write code comment that
>   describes sequential steps in a high level point of view like this:
>
> - Step 1 of 5: ...
> - Step 2 of 5: ...
> - Step 3 of 5: ...
> - Step 4 of 5: ...
> - Step 5 of 5: ...
>
> Keyboard macro can help us generate such text pattern effortlessly.
>
> - <kbd>C-x C-k C-f</kbd> and enter this format: `- Step %d of 5:`
> - <kbd>F3</kbd> to start recording.
> - <kbd>F3</kbd> again to insert the first counter value, which is `- Step 0 of 5:`
> - <kbd>RET</kbd> to move to the next line.
> - <kbd>F4</kbd> to stop recording.
> - Now press <kbd>F4</kbd> as many time as you want and see header prefix got inserted with incremental values.
>     You can insert the text any value by simply set the counter with <kbd>C-x C-k C-c</kbd>.
>
> Remember to use this the next time you write comments for your code
>   that need an ordered list to describe the steps of your algorithm.

Of course, instead of enter `- Step %d of 5:`, you can just enter `%d`. If you want the macro to repeat 90 times, just supply `90` as prefix argument.

To make it easier for you to use macro, remember that all macro commands have <kbd>C-x C-k</kbd> as prefix.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation on macro counter. Although it requires many steps, it may be useful in other places as well.

Answer (score 8):

Tu Do's answer is very good and well worth remembering for custom counter formatting, but potentially (depending on the actual use-case) a little excessive for this particular example, given that `%d` is the *default* format for the counter.

The output can therefore be achieved like so:

<kbd>M-1</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>M-9</kbd><kbd>M-0</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd>

Comment: <kbd>M-90<\kbd> needs to be <kbd>C-u 90<\kbd> for it to work on my machine.

Comment: @user2699 Are you using Emacs in terminal?

Comment: Ah, interesting. I find that `C-<n>` doesn't function in my terminal, but `M-<n>` *does* work, which is why I've taken to using the meta bindings in answers. `C-u` is always an alternative, of course. Which OS & terminal do you use?

Comment: Note that by `M-90` I mean `M-9 M-0`. I think this is the first time I've tried to condense that sort of sequence into a single kbd tag, and perhaps `M-90` is too easy to misinterpret?

Comment: Actually, M-90 works, what I tried the first time was M-9 M-0, but I've rebound M-0, and that's what caused it to fail.  I've only ever seen C-u used for repeats, so this is a great thing to learn.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a [numeric argument](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Arguments.html) to avoid typing `RET` `90` times. Just do `M-9 0 RET` to insert `90` newlines.

Alternatively, you can write a simple function that creates a range of numbers and loops over them using `number-sequence` and `dolist`:

```
(defun insert-numbers (start end)
  (interactive "nStart: \nnEnd: ")
  (dolist (ind (number-sequence start end))
    (insert (format "%d\n" ind))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of diversity:

1. <kbd>C-x * c</kbd> (Starts the calculator).
2. `1`<kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>v b</kbd>`90`<kbd>RET</kbd> creates a vector 90 elements long.
3. <kbd>V U +</kbd> calls to `accum` Calc function which acts similar to reduce, putting the intermediate results into positions of the elements which generate those. At this point you have a vector which looks like `[1, 2, .... 89, 90]`.
4. Copy the vector into the file you are editing.
5. <kbd>C-x f</kbd>`3` this will set `fill-column` to be 3 elements wide.
6. Select the contents of the vector and press <kbd>M-q</kbd> to fill paragraph (this will put every number on a separate line.

This is obviously more cumbersome than just using a recorded macro, but it has its perks in that you can create more complicated number sequences :)

Comment: By default the keyboard macro counter increases by 1, but you can use any number to add to the current counter with `C-x C-k C-a`.

Comment: @TuDo Well, you can't make a Fibonacci or factorials... :P

Comment: well if it's that complicated then isn't it better to use straight Elisp? But even so, you can bind a command that can inserts arbitrary number (such as the sequence you suggested) into the buffer at point and use it with a macro.

Comment: @TuDo that wasn't a serious comment. I don't think any sane person will want to number lines using Fibonacci numbers :) (However, I would probably use Calc rather than numbers in the macro simply because I never remember the command for it, and I use Calc often enough to perform the above from memory).

Comment: Fair enough :) But it's nice to see something unusual.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a sequence of counters starting from `START` and with step `STEP` using

<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-k</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd> `START` <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>F3</kbd> `…` <kbd>C-u</kbd> `STEP` <kbd>F3</kbd> `…` <kbd>F4</kbd>,

where `…` is anything else you want to include in your macro. This inserts the first counter, with value `START`. Afterwards, <kbd>F4</kbd> will insert the next value in the sequence and <kbd>C-u</kbd> `N` <kbd>F4</kbd> will insert the next `N` values from the sequence.

Note,

- if you don't specify `START` (i.e. if you do just <kbd>F3</kbd> `…` <kbd>C-u</kbd> `STEP` <kbd>F3</kbd> `…` <kbd>F4</kbd>) it'll start from 0.
- if you don't specify the `STEP` (i.e. skip <kbd>C-u</kbd> `STEP`), it'll be `1`.
- You can use <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-k</kbd> <kbd>C-f</kbd> to specify the format of the counter.

**This way you can enter your sequence with**

<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-k</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>F3</kbd> <kbd>F3</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>F4</kbd> <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>8</kbd> <kbd>9</kbd> <kbd>F4</kbd>

---

You can also invoke `eval-expression` (<kbd>M-:</kbd>) and evaluate

```lisp
(dotimes (i 90) (insert (format "%2d.\n" (1+ i))))
```

or more in general,

```lisp
(dotimes (i SEQ_LENGTH) (insert (format "%2d\n" (+ START (* i STEP)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you turn on the CUA minor mode (cua-mode), you can select a column of text and then fill it with a sequence of numbers using "`cua-sequence-rectangle`" (bound to `M-n` by default).